# When capturing error in command prompt in windows forms application c# is giving me exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.diagnostics

I am trying to execute some encrypt/decrypt command in command  prompt from c#  and I want to capture the console output if there is any error in command prompt .

I am trying below code

```
 var p =  Process.Start(
            @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe",
             action + @"  " + section + " " + path + " "                
            

      );
            string errorInfoIfAny = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd();
```

The above line givng me error **"StandardError has not been redirected."**

Paramaters

```
action= "-peff" (intentionally given for generating error)
section = "appSettings"
path= any folder path
```

tried below code also but not working

```
Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                // CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
            };
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe" + " " +
           action + @"  " + section + " " + path + " "; // cmd.exe spesific implementation
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();

            string errorInfoIfAny = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd();
```

Can anybody please help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror)

Comment: @KlausGütter, I tried with that approach too.(see my edited question) but not working for me .Please suggest

Comment: You need to be careful when redirecting I/O. If you redirect both output and error, then you need to read both output and error *at the same time*. Perhaps in different threads. The OS will only buffer so much data in the standard output and error streams before the child process will block.

Comment: Also "not working" is not a useful error report. Please be specific about exactly how your code is not working. Does it hang, is there an exception, etc.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman ,  It hanged

Comment: Why do you start cmd.exe and not regiis.exe directly? If you really want to go cmd.exe, start the Arguments with "/c " to make cmd.exe terminate after calling regiis. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)